# PVS-Studio creates temporary files in the project folder

Tags: pvs-studio

After each run, PVS-Studio creates a .cpp.PVS-Studio.cfg-file for each checked cpp file right in the project folder.

And it doesn't delete them after check is done. It's kinda annoying to delete them by hand or by git checkout. Can PVS-Studio be configured to create these files in some other place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The analyzer creates temporary command files for its operation to launch the analysis unit itself, to perform preprocessing and to manage the whole process of analysis. Such files are created for each project file being analyzed. You can indicate to the analyzer remove them.

PVS-Studio -> Options... -> Common Analyzer Settings -> RemoveIntermediateFiles.

Documentation: [Settings: Common Analyzer Settings](https://www.viva64.com/en/m/0012/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you clarify why this setting is not true by default?

Comment: @Amomum this setting is 'true' by default. Are you sure that you don't change this setting before?

Comment: I could set it to 'false' couple of years ago, couple of versions ago, when I tried to figure out why something didn't work. Hm. I guess it doesn't really matter if it's 'true' by default.